# In IE 8 selection of several table rows slower then Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, jquery-selectors

I have two tables aligned side by side. When I select the several rows in first table by dragging mouse over those rows  I need the same rows to be selected in second table.
In Firefox no delays when I doing this however in IE8 there is a delay and if I drag mouse too fast the rows in between are not selecting. Each row in two tables has unique id, so I know what row I have to highlight in the second table when I am highlighting the row in the first table. The id for the first table rows is "f+the order number of the row" and for the second table is "d+the order number of the row". The id for the first table is "fixedcolumntable" and for the second table is "run".
Here is my code:

```
 $("#fixedcolumntable").delegate("tr", "mousedown", function () {


       var id = ($(this).attr("id")).substring(1);

       $("#run >tbody> tr#d" + id).addClass("selectedrow");

       isMouseDown = true;

       return false; // prevent text selection
   });
  $("#fixedcolumntable").delegate("tr", "mouseover", function () {


        if (isMouseDown) {

            var id = ($(this).attr("id")).substring(1);

            $("#run >tbody> tr#d" + id).addClass("selectedrow");

        }


    });
  $("#fixedcolumntable").delegate("tr", "mouseup", function () {


        isMouseDown = false;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably want the `mouseenter` event instead of `mouseover`.  The `mouseover` event will fire multiple times if it enters any child elements, which might be partially responsible for your slowdown.

To handle the missed events, you should probably keep track of which row the mouse goes down in, then on `mouseenter` select all the rows between the current one and the first one, and deselect the others.  This has the additional benefit of letting you drag the mouse up to deselect the last row instead of having to start over again if you accidentally drag too far.